# Why is the output 6 and 21 for this java code?

Tags: java

```
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

int sum = 0;

int i = 0;

do{

  i++;

  sum = sum + i;

}

while (i <= 5);

System.out.print(i);

System.out.print(" ");

System.out.print(sum);


  }
}
```

Wondering why the output is 6, 21, shouldn't i = 5 and sum = 15. Because sum is = 0 and i is =0 and you increment them by 1 (sum 1 = sum 1 + i 1). i has to be less than or = to 5. so, i=1, i=2, i=3, i=4, i=5 and I cant be 6 because is has to be less than or equal to 5. Then you add the sum you i5+i4+i3+i2+i1 = 15

Comment: You're using a do/while loop. The condition is evaluated AFTER the execution of the block, so `i` does become 6

Comment: you can think about do 5++ while 5=5.

Comment: However, if you out i++ underneath sum = sum + i; you get 15 for sum. I don't understand why the output changes because of that

Comment: The condition `i <= 5` will stay true until `i==6`. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @ahazbatt "why tje output changes": `i++` increments the value of `i` - it sure is a difference if adding the incremented value (+1) or the not (yet) incremented one - `1 2 3 4 5 6` is *very* different than `0 1 2 3 4 5`

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke - would it be any different if the condition was evaluated **before** the block (in this case)? a `while` loop would give the same result. Similar with a `for` loop if the increment is still done inside the block.

Comment: Ah, yes, brainfart. Switching the loop type would only affect the time of the initial evaluation

Answer (score 0):

Because it's true when 5 = 5, the program will continue to run, then 5++, and then, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

When i = 5, the while condition still evaluates to *true* so the code block inside do{} will run one more time, giving you i = 6 and sum = 21 at which point the while condition will be set to false and the values will print.

Answer (score -1):

The condition while (i <= 5); becomes false when i = 6. Hence the loop is being executed 6 times and not 5, resulting in 6 and 21 as the answer.

As you are using a do-while loop the condition is checked after the increment of the loop variable i. Lets's dry run the code.

```
1st do:

i=0 and sum = 0;
then, i++ // i = 1
sum = sum + i // sum = 1

2nd do: 
i++;  // i = i+1 i.e. i = 2
sum = sum +i // sum = 1 + 2 i.e. sum = 3

3rd do:
i++; // i =3
sum = sum +i // sum =3+3 =6

4th do:
i++; // i =4
sum = sum +i // sum =6+4 =10

5th do:
i++; // i =5
sum = sum +i // sum =10+5 =15

6th do: ( As i=5 and while condition i <= 5 is still true)
i++; // i =6
sum = sum +i // sum =15+6 = 26
```

You can either use a while loop or change the termination condition to 
    while (i < 5);

Comment: a `while` loop would give the exact same result (in this case), the end condition is the factor